# "curbing out cigarette smoking"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs, australian-english

In this sentence "curbing out" reads strange. I can't find much on Google. It doesn't appear to have any meaning beyond "curbing", "inhibiting", and I am not sure the tag-along preposition "out" adds anything semantically. Is "curb out" idiomatic at all? Is it an Australian English phrasal verb?

> This Antipodean phenomenon has a strong presence in workers’ rights and political debate, especially when it comes to **curbing out** cigarette smoking. ([source](https://theculturetrip.com/pacific/new-zealand/articles/a-quick-guide-to-smoko-the-australasian-smoke-break/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently not. The GloWbE corpus has 7 instances of "curb out", 6 of which are this phrasal verb; but none of them is from Oz. (They are 1 US, 1 GB, 2 India, 1 Bangla Desh, 1 Kenya). It has no instances of "curbing out".

The iWeb corpus (bigger, and newer) has 31 instances of "curb out", but on inspection, only two of them are of this phrasal verb; and 2 of "curbing out".

So it is exceedingly rare, and I suspect a mistake (perhaps a confusion of "curb" and a different phrasal verb - maybe "cut out").

Answer (score 1):

The preposition [out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out) is used to make the meaning of a word stronger as in:

> We walked all day and were tired out (= very tired) by the time we got home.
>
> It's up to you to sort this out (= deal with it completely).

(Cambridge Dictionary)

So curb out smoking means eliminate smoking completely.